# Maintaining Data about a Database

Tags: database, database-design

I'm designing a database and I would appreciate suggestions on maintaining data that describes the tables, attributes, etc. I will make a Database Design Document, but I want something that could be more useful for updating changes to the database schema.

I read [an article](http://database-programmer.blogspot.com/2008/06/using-data-dictionary.html) that suggests using a Data Dictionary in YAML or JSON, but I haven't found much else about the subject.

My questions are: "What alternatives to data dictionaries are there for tracking this data?"

or

"From your professional experience, what is the best way to maintain this data?"

Thanks,

-N

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this link about source controlling your databases recently and thought it might help someone in the future. [Get your database under version control](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/02/get-your-database-under-version-control.html)

Also this link which I mentioned earlier [Data Dictionaries](http://database-programmer.blogspot.com/2008/06/using-data-dictionary.html)

Answer (score 0):

You might find the `comment` functionality useful, e.g.:

```
comment on table foo is 'some comments go here';
```